# Prepaid SIM card for short term - Canada

Tags: canada, cellphones, montreal

I've checked questions like:

- [Economical mobile data for US and Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42447/economical-mobile-data-for-us-and-canada)
- [Any Sim Card that works in Canada & US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29158/any-sim-card-that-works-in-canada-us)
- [Prepaid SIM card for US and Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/prepaid-sim-card-for-us-and-canada/71189#71189)

They don't really address my problem.

I will be in Montreal for 4 months. I'm looking for a SIM card. Most of the plans I saw are *with commitment* of at least one year or so. The most important part of the plan is data (for Skype calls and apps for messaging). 3 to 5 GB/month would be perfect.

What are the best options I have?

Comment: please elaborate why those questions don't help you. Are they obsolete? No focused on data? Some other reason?

Comment: There are 23 questions tagged both cellhones and canada. I think this is the most relevant to you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43958/prepaid-sim-card-with-best-data-plan-in-canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canada only has a few carriers. The big players are Bell, Rogers and Telus. Their three low cost subsidiaries are Koodo, Fido and Virgin. Freedom Mobile is the newcomer.

All of the 'low cost' providers have prepaid plans with no fixed contract. Google the provider name and "prepaid" to find their offerings. 3-5Gb is a lot of data and you may end up paying a substantial amount.

Comment: Rogers has yet another one too, Chatr Mobile. And Vidéotron is a separate possibility in Montreal.

Comment: using the site Similicious.com, you can get a SIM card for a low rate.  They'll send an appropriate SIM card to you (for your area, phone, etc)